# getting error installing rockpi4b-rk-u-boot-latest on ubuntu with latest kernal

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Please help , i invested in getting m2.nvme adapter and 1TB ssd, trying to install
rockpi4b-rk-u-boot-latest but i am getting below errors .

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f -y rockpi4b-rk-u-boot-latest
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
rockpi4b-rk-u-boot-latest is already the newest version (2017.09-2695-g7c49a7da79).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rockpi4b-rk-ubootimg (2017.09-2695-g7c49a7da79) …
Consider upgrading device bootloader with ‘rockpi4b_upgrade_bootloader.sh’.
Missing board bootloader image: /usr/lib/u-boot-rockpi4b/rockpi4b-rk-uboot.img
dpkg: error processing package rockpi4b-rk-ubootimg (–configure):
installed rockpi4b-rk-ubootimg package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rockpi4b-rk-u-boot-latest:
rockpi4b-rk-u-boot-latest depends on rockpi4b-rk-ubootimg (= 2017.09-2695-g7c49a7da79); however:
Package rockpi4b-rk-ubootimg is not configured yet.
Version of rockpi4b-rk-ubootimg on system, provided by rockpi4b-rk-ubootimg:all, is .

dpkg: error processing package rockpi4b-rk-u-boot-latest (–configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
rockpi4b-rk-ubootimg
rockpi4b-rk-u-boot-latest
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

but then if I

```
$ sudo rockpi4b_upgrade_bootloader.sh
Missing board bootloader image: /usr/lib/u-boot-rockpi4b/rockpi4b-rk-uboot.img
```

How can i fix these ?

Comment: Boot images, yuck. But simple for experts. Can you find anything https://wiki.radxa.com/Rockpi4/radxa-apt here?

Comment: Those are the steps i am already following, if it doesn’t work, rockpi m2 nvme adapter will go waste i hope i can get a adapter for converting m2.nvme to usb

Comment: @darth_epoxy : I am following this guide: https://wiki.radxa.com/Rockpi4/dev/u-boot#Build_U-Boot_and_run_it_on_ROCK_Pi_4 , when I try to install ` gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` I get error `Package 'gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Always better to stick to apt once you start however you might get it done by installing the *.deb file. Assuming you are on 20.04 and an amd machine go here https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu_9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html

Comment: @darth_epoxy i am on ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS , on arm64 platform.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an official Uuntu package for 18.04 on arm64 kit.
Looks like you are out of luck as it's only available for Fedora or ALT Linux.
Not supported in this forum
[image]